# What do we mean by bidirectional TEC?

Tags: temperature, heatsink, laser, heat-protection

I have designed a H-Bridge driving circuit for TEC where the polarity across the TEC (load) changes according to heating and cooling application. But when I am searching for TEC Module they have specified polarity for the module. So is the module birectional? If YES then how to take care of polarity change and if NO then please suggest some bidirectional TEC.
TEC is to control LASER Temperature

https://www.lumentum.com/sites/default/files/technical-library-items/4900pump_ds_cc_ae.pdf

Comment: https://www.google.ca/url?sa=t&rct=j&q=&esrc=s&source=web&cd=1&ved=0ahUKEwic2vTzwtbXAhUnzIMKHdsjDuoQFggnMAA&url=http%3A%2F%2Fwww.altechna.com%2Fdownload%2FThree%2520ways%2520to%2520get%2520bidirectional%2520TEC%2520mode.pdf&usg=AOvVaw3-6SAAI1JNxNx4vzz_xONF

Answer (score 2, accepted):

A TEC is fundamentally bipolar, at the electrical level.

However, the mechanical assembly that you buy may well be more efficient in one direction rather than the other. It may have larger or otherwise 'better' heat paths on the hot side for instance, which has to deal with more heat flow in cooling applications.

Even if it is otherwise completely symmetrical (as most are), it will be polarised for assembly documentation, so that manufacturers can install it the right way round. For instance, 'mini fridges' that can also heat the contents to 60C need to have labels on the heat-off-cool switch the right way round.

For best efficiency, a TEC should be run from steady DC. The amount of heat pumped is proportional to the current. The amount of waste heat generated is proportional to the current squared. This means that if a simple switching H-bridge PWM is used to power the TEC, a lot of waste heat will be generated, regardless of how little heat is being pumped. An LC filter should be added to the H-bridge output, which turns it into a bipolar SMPS, or class D amplifier. Having said that, a cheap class D audio amplifier modified for DC operation (input and feedback AC coupling removed) makes an ideal bipolar TEC driver.

Comment: Thank you Neil. we are using a LC filter at the output of H bridge. If TEC is bidirectional then why does it has polarity?

Comment: @Manisha, because you need to know which way to hook it up if you want it heat and which way to hook it up if you want it to cool.

Comment: @Manisha, no, it means when you design your system, you need to know which way to drive the current to pump heat one way, and which way to drive it to pump heat the other way.

Comment: @ThePhoton the assembly is : laser(object to be maintained at 25C) -- Aluminium plate -- TEC -- Thermal pad -- heat sink.

When ambient is below or above 25C, TEC should maintain a temp of 25C on the laser side.

Comment: @Manisha, nothing wrong with that. But if you're having 1000 of them built, you need to tell your manufacturing guys exactly how to assemble them. You can't just tell them, "hook it up however you want, and if it doesn't work, reverse the leads", like you might do if you're just building a one-off.

Comment: @ThePhoton Thank you for the help. I was not very familiar with TEC. Now the test is complete and its working properly.

Answer (score 0):

To use TEC cooling for a LASER, one needs to know the power dissipation of the LASER and the Cooling efficiency of the TEC. This demands low thermal resistance to transfer the heat from the LASER to cold side of the TEC to the hot side to a large heatsink.  **Reversing the heat flow is not a valid requirement here.** It will heat up immediately on initial use. Then you want to maintain it at a constant temp such as 25'C.  This can be done by clever design without adding more heat to the laser to preheat it externally and correlating Laser drop voltage with Temp (by test calibration) or with a T sensor in an active loop.

Ideally you must meet or exceed the thermal cooling capacity of LASER with some minimum safety margin and may careful selection TEC's cooling power to match or exceed the power dissipation of the Laser at the same currents. Thus they could share the same current.  Naturally you are more than doubling the laser power for the heatsink design but result in extending the life or pulse width of the Laser.  Otherwise you need excess capacity in the TEC module then regulate the cold side to the laser with a thermal sensor of some type.

Below is a SMPS + Tsens + uC method to regulate Temp.  But if one knows how to do proper thermal design, it can be done more efficiently open loop my matching the TEC cooling power to the load power and using T sense to shut off the fan for the heatsink.  It's a simple application of Ohm's Law for thermal resistance and thermal power in both devices with adequate low Thermal resistances and effective thermal resistance of the heatsink to achieve a null deg C/W rise in the laser.

Adding heat to the laser only reduces overall efficiency since the efficiency of the TEC (30%) is lower than the laser efficiency gain by externally heating it.  Self heating is free and this is a thermal application of Ohm's Law with heat mass for the storage capacity equivalent to a large capacitor (Farads) in parallel with a small R (ohms).

Define all your electro-optical-climatic parameters before you start the design.
[image]

Comment: "Reverse the heat flow is not a requirement here." The operating temperature of whole module is a wide range (0 to 60C). In order to get maximum efficiency we are planning to operate the laser at 25C. So at 0C we will first bring the temperature to 25C then will turn on the LASER. This condition we need a reverse flow of heat. Keeping this point in mind we designed a H-bridge configuration. (with filter)

Comment: Why do you need to heat the laser?  The usual specs are Operating temperature Top= -55 to 85 °C. Just turning it on 1st time will raise the temperature.  Laser voltage drops with rising temperature due to Shockley Effect giving an apparent efficiency rise.  You can measure this to determine LASER Temp. If you are worried about power efficiency, it will be worse by adding power to heat it if the ambient is 0'C. This spec makes no sense.

Comment: @Manisha Isn't that some information that should be in your question?

Comment: Manisha, show me why you think you need to heat the Laser externally.

Comment: @TonyStewart.EEsince'75 I am new to laser. I saw in datasheet that wavelength of laser changes with temperature so at ambient temperature below 25C I thought to heat the plate so that laser wavelength does not change.

Please correct if I am wrong. Link to datasheet is attached in the question.

Comment: Yeah, for DWDM applications the temperature of the lasers must be controlled so that the wavelength is correct. In fact, for many DWDM lasers, temperature may be the only tuning adjustment, aside from the physical device dimensions.

Comment: @Manisha  You must have a system spec and error budget from all sources of error for every critical parameter. Temp. is just one source of error and applying heat from a TEC full bridge is a rather naive idea that lacks considerations of overall thermal and power design

Comment: @TonyStewart.EEsince'75  I got a new TEC. How to check its functionality directly from power supply?

Comment: Manisha , normally you follow specs ,App Notes and test methods given , then if intended to use DWDM then say so in question and define specs : {0.8nm, 0.4nm or even 0.2nm} and temp range, thermal resistance, Pd , Vcc, etc

Comment: Ist possible to test the TEC without load

Comment: Is it possible you have read all the datasheets and App Notes?

Comment: @TonyStewartEEsince1975 Thankyou for your help. The testing is over and its working properly. Soft start of TEC was not happening, that was the issue.